# Run synchronous function at the end of an asynchronous function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous

Hello guys I have an asynchronous function and I have to run synchronous function at the end of the asynchronous:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(googlata);

function googlata(){
 alert('hello');
}

function endgooglata(){
 alert('i am synchronous'); 
}
```

I tried adding setInterval to the synchronous function and obviously it works ... but I do not like ...

I would like a more precise method
and of course simple ...

exists?

**EDIT**

I've created the jsfiddle but obviously does not work in straight lines because the code is more complex ... so I'll explain how it works:

I have a page.html with a simple search bar and sending the data to a paginaX.html through "get" method ...

In This is my paginaX there is code of my jsfiddle ....

When function `googlata()` is run, It create a page results in the div `id="cse"` according to research carried out in the bar.

I manipulate the URL and fetch the keywords searched ...

The SERP is created correctly.

Where is the problem???

The problem is that some results have the image and some do not ... and I want that the descriptive summaries of each result are the same distance from the margin-left ...

then the results that have the image will give them the padding ..

this happens in "`modifica()`"

But if the results page not completely created, the function `modifica()` will problems (giving the padding to the results with the image). So it is strictly necessary `modifica()` is launched at the end of `googlata ()`.

SetInterval is a very bad solution ... because sometimes `googlata()` employs more than 1300 ms set, and then it creates other errors ...

THIS IS JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/2rg86vm6/

I hope can you help me now...

Comment: Whould `function googlata(callback){
 return function() {
  alert('hello');
  callback();
 }
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(googlata(endgooglata));` answer your question ?

Comment: Do you mean that the main thread waits for the action to end?

Comment: @DragonRock i don't understand...please if is possible write an answer with an example

Comment: @user3162975 Yeah, I think Javier answered your question

Comment: @DragonRock can you help me?

Comment: @user3162975 The thing is that I don't really understand your problem, from what I understand, Javier gave the solution. Could you elaborate more your example so we can understand your problem. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxp5qr6h/) and tell me why it is not answering your problem please.

Comment: @DragonRock see edit

Comment: @user3162975 nothing really interesting here, but I think you're confused between `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. `setInterval` will repeatedly execute the function each time. `setTimeout` will only execute the function once.

I'll browse your jsfiddle to see if I find the problem.

Comment: Images ? So basically, you are loading images ? And your `modifica` function is called before all images are loaded and that's your problem ? Is that correct ? How do you load your images ?

Comment: No Dragon.... googlata() creates a serp, each result have or not have an image (that is loaded by google). With modifica() i want to add padding to result that not have the image. The problem is that i need to run modifica() at the end of googlata(), because if the serp isn't ready, modifica() will add padding also to all results...  maybe the solution is a callaback, but i don't use it :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95165/discussion-between-dragonrock-and-user3162975).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

Edited so it sends a parameter to the ending function.

```
function endgooglata(data){
  alert('i am synchronous');
  // code to process data
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(googlata);

function googlata(){
  alert('hello');
  var generatedSERP = "A new thing generated in googlata()";
  endgooglata(generatedSERP);
}
```

Comment: does not work :((
I had already tried so but nothing ... I'll explain: for time I made an example very synthesized, but in my case googlata () creates a SERP, while endgooglata () acts on the results obtained (by changing the css ). So I have to wait for the results page is created ...

Comment: Could you share your code? it is not very clear but seems like you just want to send some parameter to `endgooglata` from the callback?

Comment: no is too bigger code :/ 
there are other ways to wait for the asynchronous function to end?

Comment: If you are looking for a more complex way to handle asynchronous functions, you may want to look at JS Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I had to that the results page is end, only after "endgooglata()" cans work and add css to each result.

Comment: Do you mean `googlata` runs several times and you need `endgooglata` to run only when all the others are done?

Comment: I can not believe that there is not a method that allows me to launch a function ... at the end of an asynchronous function (when it is completed).It is absurd ..... use setInterval to remedy, but it is the perfect solution!

Comment: @user3162975, after reading some things about `google.setOnLoadCallback`, seems like it is just some kind of `onload` event that triggers only *once* when all the Google APIs have been loaded. The example above should work as far as the Google JS API has been included in the HTML code. Look at your browser console (ctrl+shift+j) to see if there is any other error. Unless you can create a little example where you can reproduce the problem, it's going to be impossible to help you any further.

Comment: @user3162975: the fiddle you created does not work: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. Anyways, looking at your code, you should move the line `google.load('search', '1');` to the end of the code so the callback and all the functions are declared before you call the API.

Comment: How is write is the Edit... I now that in jsfiddle my code doesn't work. Please read the edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95159/discussion-between-javier-conde-and-user3162975).

Answer (score 0):

I solved: D Thanks Dragon you made me think more .... I'll explain:
first td that have an image, has like a children a lot of tags but also tag "a" (that inside there will be tag image)... when google creates the serp, maybe all td are hidden, but results that will be an image, have yet all dom (maybe the image will load). So i change function "modifica()", and i add paddding ONLY for results that not have "a" tag as children ;) ...

so is true this:

```
function googlata(){
//code....
modifica();
}

function modifica(){
//code....
}
```

this is update jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2rg86vm6/1/

thanks!